# Do People Have Access to Source code after it has been published?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

after Unity games are published, are people able to access the source code of the games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the il2cpp script backend to protect your script code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I be able to do that?

Comment: It makes it more difficult to reverse engineer something compiled with Il2cpp but completely "save" it is not

Comment: @anaksky2k19 you can check this doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BuildingProject.html

Comment: yw  :) @anaksky2k19

Answer (score 3):

That depends on several factors. However, they always can disassembly and get somehow obfuscated code from your release assembly. 
This holds for C#. If you use JavaScript as your Unity language, I am not sure, because I have never used it.

If you use scripts like Lua etc., you have to handle this yourself. Also, your assets (textures, shaders, etc.) may be visible to everyone. It again depends how you set your release build.